# GCC 4.8.2 auto-vectorization fail due to cout

Tags: c++, vectorization, auto-vectorization

My code is as follows and I use GCC 4.8.2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct timespec time_start={0, 0},time_end={0, 0};
    uint8_t bitmap[20240];
    int cost;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time_start);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20240; ++i) {
        bitmap[i >> 3] |= 1 << (i&7);
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time_end);
    cost = time_end.tv_nsec - time_start.tv_nsec;
    cout << "case COST: " << cost << endl;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time_start);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20240; ++i) {
        bitmap[i >> 3] &= 1 << (i&7);
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time_end);
    cost = time_end.tv_nsec - time_start.tv_nsec;
    cout << "case COST: " << cost << endl;
    int a = bitmap[1];
    std::cout << "TEST: " << a << endl;

}
```

I compile it with

`gcc -lstdc++ -std=c++11 -O2 -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=7 -fopt-info test.cpp`

and I get `test.cpp:14: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.`.

Then I run the binary `a.out` and get `COST` more than 20000.

If I delete `std::cout << "TEST: " << a << endl;`, this code is vectorized and `COST` is less than 100.

Anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement

```
std::cout << "TEST: " << a << endl
```

You are initializing an `ostream` object which involves storage. You also use `std::endl` which is not the same as using `\n`. When you delete that statement, all this cost is not involved.

The statement before the last `cout` is also optimized away (removed) by the compiler because the value of `a` is not being used anywhere.

```
int a = bitmap[1];
```

Moreover, both the `for` loops are optimized away by the compiler because the `bitmap` values calculated by both the `for` loops will NOT be used when you remove the last `cout` statement. And there is no need of the `bitmap` array as well.

You can see the assembly that is generated for your code with the compiler version and options you have given [here](https://godbolt.org/z/G51mHh). And you can see clearly what happens when you comment out and uncomment the `cout` statement.

Comment: sorry，I can't visit https://godbolt.org/z/G51mHh. But in my opinion, I used `a` in `cout` outside `for` loop, so I think the `for` loop should be optimized too. In other words, `cout` behind `for` loop should be optimized too. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, both the `for` loops are optimized away by the compiler because the `bitmap` values calculated by the `for` loops will not be used when you remove the last `cout` statement. I have added this to the answer.